# Database network performance on Amazon web services

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am currently hosting my MySQL database on Amazon web services. I'm faced with two design choices. First, I can use a single instance in a single location which has "high network performance" according to Amazon. Or I can use more than one instance in several global locations (say America and Asia) in order to store the data closer to the customer and therefore provide higher speed. The problem is that if I go with the second choice I will have to go for a low (or at most a moderate) networking performance database because of the cost. So it's either one high network performance (in one location for everyone) or two (or three) low network performance which are close to the customer. I'm not sure which would end up being faster. Can someone shed some light on this topic please. Thanks.

Comment: Are you hosting your database on a EC2 instance, or on a RDS instance  ? From experience I prefer RDS, which allows you to create read replicas to other regions.

Comment: im hosting on RDS instance. Can i have the same database in several geographic locations?

Comment: Yes, you can have a read replica of that database/data in the other regions.  But you won't be able to write data to it, only your master database.